# How to import Netbeans keyboard mapping into Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans, ide

I am PHP and JS developer. My native dev environment is Netbeans + Webstorm. Now I have to code in .net web API, and I am not used to Visual Studio shortcuts. For me the standard is set by Netbeans, and I would like to have familiar shortcuts in VS2015. Could You please tell how to import Netbeans shortcuts into VS2015? I did googling `visual studio import keyboard mapping` but I can't find anything useful.